# Visual Studio to Make

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

While I love the Unix toolset family(including its black sheep Make) the project I'm working on currently is cross platform. That means having a Visual studio project ready for build.

So my question is, **is there a tool/plugin for importing a Make file into VS or conversely is there a way to export a visual studio project into Make?** Or any textual form, actually. I could write a script that parsed that into a Make file.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest making using [Cmake](http://www.cmake.org/)... which will generate a set of makefiles or a visual Studio Project.